# linux shell command mv many files

Tags: linux, shell, mv

I have many files like **1a1, 2a2, 3a3** and I want to mv the file names to **1b1, 2b2, 3b3**. That means to replace **'a'** to **'b'** in these file names.

I have tried the command like:

```
for f in */*; do
  mv "$f" "${f/a/b}"
done
ls | xargs -i mv {} ${{}/a/b}  
ls | xargs -i mv {} \`echo {}|tr -t 'a' 'b'\`
```

but none works.
I know a command 
**rename 'a' 'b' ***
can work.

But I still want to figure out how to use `for`, `xargs` involved with `other cmds` to do this work. After all, in every day use, they are much general than simple `rename` command.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Is it exactly 3 characters? or `a` can be be in any position?

Comment: For a start, `\\` isn't a valid path separator, and you need to quote your variables.

Comment: yeah, I have corrected them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for old in *
do new=$(echo "$old" | sed -e 's/a/b/')
   echo mv "$old" "$new" &>2
   mv "$old" "$new"
done
```

This example will allow you to guess more complex name transformations as you learn how to use `sed(1)` command to do the name transformations.

The program walks all the command line parameters to the for loop, in each loop, the program gets a new variable `new` with the transformation of the original `$old` name. Then you only have to execute the command with the old and new values.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to know with rename:

```
rename 's/(.*)a(.*)/$1b$2/' *
```

Comment: The problem with `rename` is that there are a couple of different versions out there each having a pretty different, sometimes limited, feature set.